# динамический массив, указание

Tags: c++, массивы

можно ли задать массив следующим образом? язык С++

```
int arr[*N]={*A};
```

> test.cpp:7:16: error: variable-sized object ‘arr’ may not be initialized
>   N и A - введенные переменные

Comment: int arr[*N]={*A};

Comment: отредактируй вопрос, добавив в него **всю** необходимую информацию.

Comment: А что вам мешает это проверить самому?

Comment: что за язык используется?

Comment: Студийный компилятор не поддерживает VLA. Если `*N` не известно в момент компиляции - тогда не будет работать.

Comment: известно` int *A,*N,*D;
cin >>*A>>*N>>*D;
int arr[*N]={*A};`

Comment: Это уже известно ВО ВРЕМЯ ВЫПОЛНЕНИЯ, а не компиляции.

Comment: Размер массива должен быть константой или это должен быть динамический массив.

Answer (score 5):

Поскольку во время компиляции никаких адресов нет и в помине, то такая конструкция невозможна - размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции.

И, кстати

```
 int *A,*N,*D; cin >>*A>>*N>>*D;
```

ошибочный код. Вы имеете *неинициализированные* переменные-указатели, указывающие куда угодно... и пытаетесь считывать данные куда угодно. Undefined behaviour со всеми вытекающими. При везении - программа аварийно завершится, при меньшем везении - будет продолжать работать...

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор вам сообщает, что вы пытаетесь создать массив переменной длины, когда размерность массива определяется во время выполнения программы. Однако стандарт C++ не разрешает создавать такие массивы, хотя некоторые компиляторы имеют собственные расширения языка, которые позволяют это делать.

Поэтому вам будет проще, если вы вместо массива будете использовать стандартный класс `std::vector`.

Например,

```
std::vector<int> v = { *A };
```

В общем случае изначально задавать количество элементов в векторе нет необходимости, так как их число может меняться по мере добавления или удаления элементов вектора.

В языке C вы действительно можете создавать массивы переменной длины, хотя такая поддержка не является обязательной для компиляторов языка C.